ModuleNotFoundError in Python venv even after verifying the executable and pip are correct
Trying to run a project downloaded from github. Running a virtual environment. With a very painstaking install process due to its self-conflicting requirements.txt, I manage to pip install all of the package requirements, but I am still getting a ModuleNotFoundError on several modules.
I created and activated my virtual environment by navigating to my project directory in powershell and running
python -m venv .venv and then .venv/Scripts/activate.
With the venv activated:
I ran pip install -r requirements.txt and resolved the conflicts manually. None of these conflicts are modules named in the errors.
I ran python -u main.py per the instructions from the project.
This produces many ModuleNotFoundErrors.
My next step was to ensure that pip install and the python executable are the ones I want to run so I ran where.exe python Which shows C:\[mypath]\.venv\Scripts\python.exe and python -m site also shows the expected paths.
I ran python -m pip --version which shows pip 24.0 from C:\[mypath]\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9) Which seems correct to me
Pip list shows all the packages installed.
I cannot figure out why Python cannot find these modules.
Edit:
Everything seems to work fine when I run each .py file individual. I only get the ModuleNotFoundErrors when I try to run the whole thing at once from main.py.
The Main file looks something like this:
import subprocess

files_to_run = [
    'file1.py',
    'file2.py',
    'file3.py'
]

for file in files_to_run:
    subprocess.run(['python', file])


If case you are using VScode, you may want to select the virtual environment on the lower right, instead of the global environment (besides activating it as you mentioned). I faced this issue before and that solved it.

I am not using VScode, but this is good to keep in mind for the future

One last thing to make sure, is this the first time you use virtual environments? If so, try making a new project with a simpler requirements.txt file, add some of the modules listed (make sure those are not installed globally), and see if you can install and run a simple Python script (example: import pandas as pd in your main.py script).

It is my first time using venv. I did a quick test with a small test script with pandas and it does indeed work properly

I could provide more help if I had access to some of the requirements. Can you make a small test example? A requirements.txt file with some of the packages (hopefully 2 or 3), and a python script importing them so I can test it.

The actual requirements list is very large but these are the files that are not being detected: colorama, pandas, transformers, networkx, PIL

So I think I solved the issue:
The problem seems to be in the main file, when subprocess.run is running the python command, it runs the python.exe from the user install, NOT from the virtual environment. Specifying the path to the venv python.exe fixed the issue.
